# Is the module descriptor's main-class-attribute available for JAR files only?

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

In JPMS the compiled module descriptor can contain more information than its source.
That means module-info.java has no valid syntax to define a main class, but module-info.class
can have this information attached.

One can set the main class for a modular jar while creation like this:
`jar --create --file out.jar --main-class simple.module.Runner $(find . -name "*.class")`

With the reflection API the properties of a compiled module descriptor can be checked:

```
Path mdPath = FileSystems.newFileSystem(Path.of("out.jar")).getPath("module-info.class");
ModuleDescriptor md = ModuleDescriptor.read(Files.newInputStream(mdPath));
System.out.println(md.mainClass()); // Optional[simple.module.Runner]
```

There is also a Builder for creating module descriptors, where one can set the main class property.
But I see no way to serialize this object as module-info.class file.

```
ModuleDescriptor md = ModuleDescriptor.newModule("simple.module")
                .mainClass("simple.module.Runner")
                .build();
```

As far as I can see there is no possibilty that the java compiler can create module descriptors with the 'module main class' property set.

It is possible to copy the jar-modified module-info.class back to the exploded module and execute that, with the added main-class property working:
`java -p . -m simple.module`
instead of:
`java -p . -m simple.module/simple.module.Runner`

Is there a reason why one cannot declare a main class in module-info.java?
Why is no javac option available to set the main-class in a module descriptor?

Comment: I am slightly confused, do you intend to have multiple main-class within a JAR to run them without specifying explicitly in the terminal.

Comment: No, I just want to set only one class as main class file.

Comment: The jmod tool also can set the main class with `--main-class <String: class-name>`